# higcharts highstock issue with flag position

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using [**Highstock flags**](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/flag-series) in my charts, while using squirepin flag shapre with **template**, flag is overlapping the series, but if I use it without templates it works fine.

```
series: [{
    name: 'USD to EUR',
    data: data,
    id: 'dataseries',
    tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 4
    }
}, {
    type: 'flags',
    data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(year, 1, 22),
        title: '<span><b>Name</b>:John Doe </span><br><span> Age:20</span><br><span>Gender:Male</span>',
        text: 'Shape: "squarepin"'
    }],
    onSeries: 'dataseries',
    shape: 'squarepin'
}]
```

Here is my **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sorb999/rLoa7ts8/)** with issue,

Expected output: 
[image]

It should be above the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `y` attribute to series like

```
series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: data,
        id: 'dataseries',
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 4
        }
    }, {
        type: 'flags',
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(year, 1, 22),
            title: '<span><b>Name</b>:John Doe </span><br><span> Age:20</span><br><span>Gender:Male</span>',
            text: 'Shape: "squarepin"'
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(year, 3, 28),
            title: 'A',
            text: 'Shape: "squarepin"'
        }],
        onSeries: 'dataseries',
        shape: 'squarepin',
        y:-70  //place required value
    }]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3es8coso/) demo